# Irreducibility of reflexive compositions of polynomials (II)

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Given an unknown polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, write on the blackboard a finite expression that defines a polynomial $q \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ by using only constants $1, x, p$ of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication and polynomial composition. For instance,

$$p(x^2 + p^3(x^4 - 4))^5 + 6.$$

I'll refer to a $q$ defined in this way as a *reflexive composition*. In case one knew that all the specializations of $q$ obtained by varying $p$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, could one conclude that there must exist another reflexive composition $q'$, all of whose specializations divide the respective specializations of $q$?

For example, if $q = p \circ g \circ p$ for a fixed $g \in \mathbb{Z}[x][y]$, then this indeed must be the case (in fact, it follows from Hilbert's irreducibility theorem that $g$ must be of the form $x + yh$ for some $h \in \mathbb{Z}[x][y]$, thus $q'$ can be taken to be $p$).

I would also appreciate a reference to any result in this direction or to a discussion of a related problem.

Thank you.

Albertas

Comment: Perhaps the near-rings of polynomial functions are related. I known nothing on this subject, but if they are really related (check with a google scholar search) then adding suitable tags to your question might attract the right experts.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I would like to add the near-ring tag, but there doesn't seem to be one among the existing tags here (and, due to insufficient "reputation", I cannot create one). Also, though $(\mathbb{Z}[x], +, \circ)$ forms a near-ring, this structure does not capture multiplication of free variable, so I do not see if the problem could be fully contained in this context.

Comment: Note that $f^2$ is the composition of $f$ with the squaring function and $fg$ is the unique solution of $fg+fg=(f+g)^2-f^2-g^2$. Hence multiplication is uniquely defined by the near-ring with one fixed element (the squaring function). Besides, Pliz's book about near-rings uses the terms "composition ring" or "tri-operation algebra" for the structure you use. Ideals in this context seem to be studied, and might be related to your question.

Comment: Thank you! I should be able to have a look at Pilz's book in a couple of weeks.